# Scrolling a WebView using ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

I want to be able to use a ScrollViewer to scroll my content all at once, so I have a Grid with two controls; a Button and a Grid holding the WebView.

Is it possible when I scroll through the WebView that the title gets hidden too (scrolled up)?

My Code is below

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" IsScrollInertiaEnabled="True" x:Name="ContentScroll">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <Button Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=Theme.PrimaryForeground, FallbackValue='#000000'}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,5,3,0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=entry.Title}" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}" FontWeight="Normal" x:Name="tittle" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>

                    <Grid Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <WebView x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: You want to clip the top of the `WebView`? If the user taps and drags the content of the webview, it would scroll, not the scrollviewer. Putting a `WebView` in anything but a statically positioned container doesn't work well typically.